# Trouble casting text datatype to varchar

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, exception, casting

I have the following TSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #RefTables(RefTable varchar(50) , row varchar(50), id int)

insert into #RefTables
   select 
      CONVERT(varchar, tblReferenceTables.description, 0) as RefTable, 
      CONVERT(varchar, tblReferenceTableRows.description, 0) as row, 
      tblReferenceTableRows.id
   from 
      tblReferenceTables 
   inner join 
      tblReferenceTableRows on tblReferenceTables.id = tblReferenceTableRows.ref_table_id
   where 
      tblReferenceTables.type_id in (0, 2)
      and tblReferenceTables.id in (3, 4, 14)
```

But returns the exception:

> Insert error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Would someone kindly tell me what's wrong with this?  I have tried using `CAST` to no success either. The query executes just fine if I don't use the temp table.

I need to change datatype to `varchar` so I can aggregate on the text fields in the original table.

**REFERENCE:**

- SQL Server 2005 Enterprise

**EDIT**

It appears that because the names of the fields (`description` respectively) in the original tables does not match the temp table field's names respectively, appears to be the cause of the error.  If I add another temp table renaming the text fields everything works.  This appears to be a limitation of the SQL engine?

**EDIT 2**

Using `marc_s's` suggestion also resolve the error w/o the need for another temp table - THANKS!!!  Please move your comment to answer so that I may mark it as the resolution for this issue.

Comment: What DBMS are you using and what version? I can't replicate this error on MS SQL 2008.

Comment: Without DDL it's hard to be sure, but your SQL looks ok to me.  What happens if you either specify the inset column list, or remove the aliases from your select?

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure what you mean be specify the inset column list, but removing the aliases makes no difference - still get the error.

Comment: Recommendations: (1) always specify the **column list** on an `INSERT` - `insert into #RefTables(RefTable, Row, Id)` - (2) always specify a **length** when converting to `varchar` - `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ....`

Comment: @AndroidAddict - marc's comment is **not** the answer. Probably you opened a new connection when you tried it hence no old `#temp` table hanging around. If you try your *original* code in a new query window you will also find it works!

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation for this error is that at the time the code shown in the question is compiled there already exists a table called `#RefTables` with a different schema.

Try running `DROP TABLE #RefTables` to clean this up then execute the code in the question in a separate batch.

A simple demo of this error is

```
CREATE TABLE #RefTables (x INT, Y INT)
  
GO

CREATE TABLE #RefTables (x INT)

INSERT INTO #RefTables VALUES (1)
```

Which throws

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> Column name or number of supplied
> values does not match table definition.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my edits delineate what is actually wrong and also how to resolve.

Comment: @AndroidAddict - Your edits just show you have misinterpreted what was actually wrong. SQL Server doesn't care what the column names are in the source and marc's suggestions are about best practice and do not alter the semantics.